# Using regex to find a url pattern then redirect to a new one?

Tags: regex, google-chrome-extension

Sorry for the sloppy title, what i am trying to accomplish is an extension that will read my current url, and if it falls under a certain pattern then it will redirect me to a new page.

To further explain here is an example:

Every time i get a url like this: http://giant.gfycat.com/DownrightDismalElkhound.gif (giant.*.gif)

I want to be redirected to this: http://gfycat.com/DownrightDismalElkhound (<strike>giant.</strike>*<strike>.gif</strike>)

I have never written a chrome extension before so i was hoping someone could point me to a good resource to be able to learn how to do this.

Comment: [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (especially the architecture part), [WebRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). As-is, this question is probably going to be closed; come back when you have a more defined problem.

Comment: @Xan Even if this does get removed i am grateful you got me started. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = window.location.href;

if (!url.match(/giant\./) && !url.match(/\.gif$/)){
  
  window.location.href = 'http://www.cnn.com';
  
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but before I search it up (I'm on mobile now) would I be able to go to the part of the URL I didn't cut out? Could I store it, modify it (by removing the parts) then go to it?